# Centering Caption on Table

Tags: tables, captions

so I know this has been asked many times before, but none of the solutions seem to be working for me. So I have a table and a caption on said table. But the caption is aligned to something on the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\title{Tables for Main doc}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{table}[H]
\captionsetup{aboveskip=0pt,font=it}
\small{
\centering
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5in}{-1.5in}  
\begin{center}
\caption{Linearised Data ($d$, $d^{-1}$)}
\label{Table 1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rule{0pt}{3ex}  \textbf{Wire Diameter} & \textbf{$\Delta d$} & \textbf{$\% \Delta d$} & \textbf{$\frac{1}{d}$}  & \textbf{$\%\Delta \frac{1}{d}$} & \textbf{$\Delta \frac{1}{d}$}\\
$d$ (mm) &  &  & (mm$^{-1}$) &  & (mm$^{-1}$) \\
\hline
\textbf{0.08} & 0.0001 & 12.5 & 0.00125 & 0.0156 & \\
\hline
\textbf{0.3} & 0.0001 & 3 & 0.0003 & 0.0009 & \\
\hline
\textbf{0.45} & 0.005 & 2.2 & 0.011 & 0.024 & \\
\hline
\textbf{0.56} & 0.0001 & 1.8 & 0.00018 & 0.00032 & \\
\hline
\textbf{0.78} & 0.005 & 1.3 & 0.0065 & 0.0085 & \\
\hline
\textbf{0.93} & 0.005 & 1.1 & 0.0055 & 0.0061 & \\
\hline
\textbf{1.25} & 0.01 & 0.8 & 0.008 & 0.006  &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
}        
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have separated the table from the rest of the document if anyone could take a look at it. This has honestly got me perplexed as a new Latec user.
[image: Table in question]

Comment: Unrelated: `\small` does not take any arguments. Since you're already inside an environment (`table`) you can just use `\small`

Comment: And please don't use the `H` specifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simplified code works fine:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{chngpage}
    \usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}, showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \author{Pepe Le Pew}
    \title{Tables for Main doc}
    \date{}
    \begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{aboveskip=0pt,font=it}
    \caption{Linearised Data ($d$, $d^{-1}$)}
    \label{Table 1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \rule{0pt}{3ex} \textbf{Wire Diameter} & \textbf{$\Delta d$} & \textbf{$\% \Delta d$} & \textbf{$\frac{1}{d}$} & \textbf{$\%\Delta \frac{1}{d}$} & \textbf{$\Delta \frac{1}{d}$}\\
    $d$ (mm) & & & (mm$^{-1}$) & & (mm$^{-1}$) \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0.08} & 0.0001 & 12.5 & 0.00125 & 0.0156 & \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0.3} & 0.0001 & 3 & 0.0003 & 0.0009 & \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0.45} & 0.005 & 2.2 & 0.011 & 0.024 & \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0.56} & 0.0001 & 1.8 & 0.00018 & 0.00032 & \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0.78} & 0.005 & 1.3 & 0.0065 & 0.0085 & \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0.93} & 0.005 & 1.1 & 0.0055 & 0.0061 & \\
    \hline
    \textbf{1.25} & 0.01 & 0.8 & 0.008 & 0.006 &\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the help.